# How to update content of a Bootstrap modal loaded using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, symfony-forms

I've a bootstrap Modal with users list, inside which I'm displaying another modal for adding a new user. The Add new User Modal is fetched using Ajax. When I add a new user using Ajax, I want to update the div with Ajax response message(.alert-success or .alert-danger in bootstrap).

Right Now the user is loaded but I can't show the message as the modal itself is loaded using Ajax.

```
$('body').on("click", "#createGroupUserModual .submit", function (e) {
var alertContainer = $(document).find('#groupUserFormCreate').find("#alerts");
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#groupUserFormCreate').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: $('#groupUserFormCreate').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success " + response.message);
            var returnMessage = "<div class='alert alert-success'>"+response.message+"</div>";
           //this below line is not updating the contents with the message.
            alertContainer.html(returnMessage);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log("failure is here " + response.message);
            var returnMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+response.message+"</div>";
            alertContainer.html(returnMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that not same code for redraw de alertContent, it only exists when response is success but not in errro, under $.ajax query
So:

```
error: function(response) {
                        console.log("failure is here " + response.message);
                        var returnMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+response.message+"</div>";
 alertContainer.html(returnMessage);

                    }
```

Try this code, added the redraw html in error.
Expect will be.

Comment: I'll update the question. I have checked it. I had added it before and removed somewhere in the middle while testing. I get a success but still the container is not updated with the message.

Comment: Will be becose, when  gets error from jquery, will not have response.message, try first to look inside jquery objet: console.log(response, ':::');